# HTML special characters not displayed properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, htmlspecialchars

I have two PHP files and when I fetch data from database on these pages and display them using `print_r` both the pages display content in different way.

Actually I have some HTML special characters in my content with I have escaped using `htmlspecialchars` before string in MySQL database.

when I fetch them display it on page1.php it is displayed as

```
My ‘pop’ to display
```

but on page2.php it is displayed as

```
My &#8216;pop&#8217; to display
```

I also want to mention that page1.php is my webpage and I have print_r just to check the issue on page2.php where page2.php is a api page where I was using echo json_encode to write data but to check the issue I have replaced it with print_r

Comment: i guess its utf8 format issue so before you run json_encode function use utf8_encode then run json_code

Comment: "I have escaped using `htmlspecialchars` before string in MySQL database." Well, there's your problem. **Don't do this**. You should be inserting your data with SQL escaping, not HTML escaping. HTML escaping is to be used when you display things on a page and only then.

Comment: I tried but utf8_encode doesn't work in this case

Comment: @tadman I removed htmlspecialchars but still it is automatically converted to &#8216;pop&#8217;

Comment: is it Collation issue of database column? mine is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Because my data in database is already manipulated using htmlspecialchars and even after removing htmlspecialchars I was not able to correct the data to I found this solution to convert all html encoded characters back to original

Here is the simple code for doing this

```
$input = "This is the &#8216;text&#8217; I fetched";
$output = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $input);
echo $output;
```

Referance: http://www.codewithasp.net/2016/11/html-entity-decode-to-original-php.html

**UPDATED**

Alternatively we can also use html_entity_decode to do the same which I found after tadman's comment.

Comment: Don't encourage people to write their own junk when there's a [built-in function `html_entity_decode` that does this already](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). Step 1 is check the documentation, not start coding.

Comment: I think this piece of code is also on same documentation link which yo shared. I just used what I found in my search. Anyway thanks for sharing this solution. I will update this in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

For Display use this code.

```
$message = "My ‘pop’ to display";

echo htmlspecialchars($messge, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I am not using htmlspecialchars now but still my text is automatically converted to My &#8216;pop&#8217; to display. is it database Collation issue? mine is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Yes it's database collation issue. when you insert data in database that time skip html character using mysql_real_escape_string  function.

Comment: so how can I correct that? do I have to use some other collation?